# A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException' occurred in System.Data.OracleClient.dll VBA

Tags: vb.net, oracle

Can anyone help me solve this issue please. I'm getting this error

I checked the System.Data.OracleClient path and it is correct.

```
Public oradb As String = "Data Source=DB;User ID=login;Password=psw;Unicode=True"
Public cn As New OracleClient.OracleConnection ' Visual Basic


Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Data.OracleClient
Imports System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType

Public Class Form1

    Dim cmd As New OracleClient.OracleCommand

    Dim query, query1 As String
   
    Private Sub RF_Insert()
        Try
            If cn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
                cn.Open()
            End If
            For i = 0 To Grid_RF.Rows.Count - 1

                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into tmp_table (operator_name,real_minutes,insert_date) values('" & Grid_RF.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString & "', '" & Grid_RF.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value & "','" & nDate & "')"
                cmd.Connection = cn
                cmd.ExecuteReader()
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
    enter code here
```

Comment: `Catch ex As Exception` is really bad. What is the full error message?

Comment: http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/csharp-executereader-executenonquery.htm

Comment: Do you run the application in 64-bit mode?

Comment: ExecuteReader() does not make any sense for an INSERT command.

Comment: The insert will most likely fail, because of the Date string. Use prepared statements with bind parameters.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again and again, however your code is full of errors. You specify a connectionString but you don't use it when you open the connection. Maybe Google for VB tutorial.

Comment: @TimWilliams - how is the linked document related to the question? It handles C# and SQL-Server instead of Oracle.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - I was wondering whether `ExecuteReader` vs. `ExecuteNonQuery` (designed for SQL *which is not intended to return records*) was the issue.  That's the focus of the linked post, and you yourself pointed out the issue in your comment.

Comment: Why not give us a clue and say which line the error occurs on?

Comment: System.Data.OracleClient is deprecated the types will be removed in future versions. MS recommends that you use a third party provider.

Comment: Don't write a Catch without code in it. It will just swallow errors. Don't declare connections or commands outside the method were they are used. Using...End Using blocks will declare, close and dispose even if there is an error. Always use parameters instead of concatenating strings for the sql command.